# How to clone radio buttons in jQuery with default checked status?

Tags: jquery

I am having difficulty cloning radio buttons with their default checked status.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="a2">
    <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="name" checked="checked" /> Name
    <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="url" /> URL
    <div class="text">
        <textarea name="name[]">Enter name: </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="url">
        <textarea name="url[]">http://</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="clone" value="Clone" />
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.a2 [name]').change(function() { 
if($(this).val() == "name") {
    $(this).parent().find('.url').css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent().find('.text').css({'visibility': 'visible', 'display':'block'});
} else {
    $(this).parent().find('.text').css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display':'none'});
    $(this).parent().find('.url').css({'visibility': 'visible', 'display':'block'});
}
});

$('.clone').click(function() {
    var p = $('.a2:first').length;
    var cloned = $('.a2:first').clone()
    .find('.a2 [name]').attr('name', 'selection_' + ++p).end()
    .appendTo('.container');
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is the Clone button should clone the entire set of radio buttons and the text areas with the default checked status also cloned in the new set. The radio buttons should be renamed by increasing the prefix number such as selection_2, selection_3, etc on each copy so that the radio selection on each set work independently.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tz66H/

Comment: You need to specify a different name to each radio group. Like you have done for selection_1 and then after first clone it would be selection_2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".container").on("change", ".a2 input[name^='selection_']", function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "name") {
        $(this).parent().find('.url').css({
            'visibility': 'hidden',
                'display': 'none'
        });
        $(this).parent().find('.text').css({
            'visibility': 'visible',
                'display': 'block'
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('.text').css({
            'visibility': 'hidden',
                'display': 'none'
        });
        $(this).parent().find('.url').css({
            'visibility': 'visible',
                'display': 'block'
        });
    }
});

$('.clone').click(function () {
    var p = $('.a2').length;
    var cloned = $('.a2:first').clone()
        .find('input:radio').attr('name', 'selection_' + ++p).end()
        .appendTo('.container');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz66H/4/)

Comment: Yes your solution is pretty neat. I couldn't have guessed this line:
`$(".container").on("change", ".a2 input[name^='selection_']", function (event) {`

What's the reason my original line $('.a2 [name]').change(function() wouldn't work? I'm unable to figure out.

There is one more thing though. When you click on URL radio button and clone, it clones the URL checked with it's relevant textarea. What I wanted was regardless of what radio button selected, the clone should always select Name radio by default. Is that possible?

Comment: See, you are adding some content to DOM dynamically and for this we need to attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements by using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Please read the documents on `on` for more details. As a suggestion, whenever you are creating something dynamic, try to use `on` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var p = $('.a2 input[name=^="selection_"]').length + 1;
var cloned = $('.a2:first').clone()
.find('.a2 [name]').attr('name', 'selection_' + p).end()
.appendTo('.container');
```

**Tested Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('.a2 [name]').change(function()
        { 
            if($(this).val() == "name")
            {
                $(this).parent().find('.url').css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display':'none'});
                $(this).parent().find('.text').css({'visibility': 'visible', 'display':'block'});
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).parent().find('.text').css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display':'none'});
                $(this).parent().find('.url').css({'visibility': 'visible', 'display':'block'});
            }
        });

        $('.clone').click(function()
        {
            var p = $('.a2 input[name^="selection_"]').length + 1;
            alert(p);
            var cloned = $('.a2:first').clone().find('input[name^="selection_"]').attr('name', 'selection_' + p).end().appendTo('.container');
        });
    });

</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="name" checked="checked" /> Name
        <input type="radio" name="selection_1" value="url" /> URL
        <div class="text">
            <textarea name="name[]">Enter name: </textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="url">
            <textarea name="url[]">http://</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="clone" value="Clone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.clone').click(function() {
   var p = $('.a2 input[value="name"]').length + 1;
   $('.a2:first').clone().find('input[value="name"]').attr({name:'selection_' + p}).end().appendTo('.container');
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Tz66H/3/)